# JBoss AS vs WildFly 8

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

Can anyone please give me the main difference between JBoss AS 7 and WildFly 8?

I'm going to start a very important project and I have to choose between JBoss AS 7 and WildFly 8 (for this project I'm going to use GWT, JPA/Hibernate and [jBPM](http://www.jbpm.org/) 6).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

WildFly 8 is the next iteration of the JBoss application server after JBoss AS 7 / EAP 6.

Basically:

- JBoss AS 7.x = JEE6
- JBoss EAP 6.x = JEE6
- WildFly 8.x = JEE7

[Red Hat](https://www.redhat.com/en) typically backports security fixes from newer versions into older versions, Red Hat also typically releases "feature packs" that allow you to access newer features/specs.

So if it is a very important project and you do not need JEE7 specs, you may want to use JBoss EAP which is the productized version of JBoss AS 7.

Otherwise you may want to use [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/) if you need the more cutting edge specs and features.

---

### Related

See JBoss AS / WildFly [versions history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

WildFly is the new name of JBoss AS so that the company JBoss and the application server JBoss cannot induce confusion anymore.

Think of WildFly 8 as JBoss AS 8, just with a different name.

JBoss 7 is an implementation of JavaEE 6.
WildFly 8 is an implementation of JavaEE 7.

Comment: jboss is not a company it's redhat.

Answer (score 3):

The JBoss application server is the "commercialized" version of the community Wildfly application server.  Red Hat offers support contracts for JBoss and has a long term maintenance schedule for JBoss.

The versions are also different.  JBoss EAP 6 corresponds to Wildfly 7.