# What Is The Wildfly Equivalent Of JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: wildfly, jboss6.x

I am investigating an application the requires JBoss EAP 6.4.
However, I don't want to pay the (~$30k) annual license.

What is the equivalent Wildfly version?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915850/jboss-as-vs-wildfly-8) for more details.  Basically you can decide for yourself if you need to have the commercial version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest version you will find is JBoss AS 7.1.1. This is very similar to EAP 6.4 but not exact.  EAP 6.4 exact match would be closer to AS 7.5 but a binary for that has never been released. (You can build it yourself from source)

I would try 7.1.1 and see if it works. Moving to Wildfly 8 is a bigger change and I wouldn't expect it to work out of the box unless the vendor supports WF/EAP 7.

I also noticed that JBoss AS 7.2.0 is in maven central but not released on their web page. You might want to try this out and see if it works.

The [Maven Cargo plugin](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/JBoss+7.5.x.html) gives a good description of the versions - although as mentioned above, not all binaries are available to download.

```
JBoss EAP version 6.1 = the build from JBoss AS version 7.2 released in May 2013
JBoss EAP version 6.2 = the build from JBoss AS version 7.3 released in October 2013
JBoss EAP version 6.3 = the build from JBoss AS version 7.4 released in June 2014
JBoss EAP version 6.4 = the build from JBoss AS version 7.5 released in October 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested both, JBoss 7.1.1 AS and WildFly 8.2.1 and I think that is mostly seems at the last one. If you check the dates, JBoss EAP 6.4 and WildFly 8 are parallels in 2015 but JBoss 7 has stopped in 2012.