# Migrate from Jboss EAP 6.4 to WildFly

Tags: java, server, jboss, migration, wildfly

I need to migrate my application from Jboss EAP 6.4 to WildFly. I am new to Jboss and not a developer. My application is currently deployed on Jboss 6.4 and it's working fine.

Can you please provide me with details on to how to migrate to WildFly server.

1. Which WildFly version should I use?
2. Are there any development work to migrate?
3. How to change configurations (like standalone.xml)?

Any hint or help to do this migration is appreciated. If you need any further information I can provide any details.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. We don't know how complex your application is nor what it does. Wildfly has gone to a much more frequent release schedule but the version will depend on your needs. I would start by trying to use the most recent version of Wildfly (12 as of this writing) and see what breaks. It is very possible that you need to change some code but not guaranteed.  And let us know when you [crosspost](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277639) too - some of us might be answering in multiple places otherwise.

Comment: Any reason for the move from the commercially supported version to the community edition, rather than EAP 7.0 or EAP 7.1?

Comment: As has been mentioned already, you have given no details at all of the app, so it's impossible for anyone to comment really. As for changes to standalone(-full).xml, I would start by seeing how your current configuration compares with the version from a clean install to see what changes were made. This should then add as a pretty good starting point to then know what changes you need for EAP 7. The syntax might be different, but the redhat docs for 6->7 should help with this and if you have commercial support, you can ask RedHat for help with anything you get stuck in that.

Comment: Depending on exactly what the app does and how much it used just standard JavaEE and what was more EAP specific, there is a reasonable chance that you might need to make changes to the source code of your app, so it might be worth checking you have the source code so you can get someone to update if needed

Comment: What is the motivation for this change? Just that 6.4 is getting towards then end of it's life and you don't want to leave too late? Might be better to just make sure you are up to date with your security patches (6.4.17 I think we are on now)

Comment: Thank you very much all guys, stdunbar, and Will T to help me on this topic, Your help is very useful and save my day. @stdunbar I apologize to crosspost this question.

The reason for the move to WildFly is JBoss subscription. There are some problems with subscription payments.

I can give you may application details after discussing with my developers. 

For the configuration changes, I will try as you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following resources, and my own personal experience, I find that Wildfly 8.2.1 is the closest I can get to EAP 6.4.

- [What Is The Wildfly Equivalent Of JBoss EAP 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954144/what-is-the-wildfly-equivalent-of-jboss-eap-6-4)
- https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_6

In terms of standalone.xml changes, I find that most of the changes I make to JBOSS EAP 6.4 and Wildfly 8.2.1 are interchangeable, but anything that includes an XML namespace will need to be updated. For example the loggers, datasources, security-domains use the same XML configuration, but their XML namespace has changed.

Now, as many have mentioned, this will vary tremendously based on your individual app and what subsystem components you're making use of. My own app tends to deploy using very few of the JBOSS capabilities/components, intentionally so that I can shift servers somewhat painlessly. However, other apps can integrate much more tightly and would require a great deal more to migrate.